# Continuity and measurability

Tags: continuity, lebesgue-measure

this question concerns continuity and measureability.

Am I right in thinking that if $f>0$ for all x then $\log(f(\lambda x)/f(x))$ is a continuous function for all $x$. Does this then mean that 
$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\log\left(\frac{f(\lambda x)}{f(x)}\right)=\log\left(\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f(\lambda x)}{f(x))}\right)$?
I know that $f$ is measurable if this is any use. Sorry I forgot to say that $\lambda>0$.

Hmmm does the fact that $\frac{f(\lambda x)}{f(x)}\rightarrow 1$ uniformly in $\lambda$ mean that 
$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\log\left(\frac{f(\lambda x)}{f(x)}\right)=\log\left(\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f(\lambda x)}{f(x))}\right)$?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is $f$ continuous? If $f$ is then your composition is continuous. I don't think measurability is enough but I'll try to think of a counterexample...

Comment: Edited my answer to deal with your new condition that $\lambda > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

No, if $\lambda = 2$ and you take $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x) = 2$ if $x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{2\}$ and $f(2) = 1$, then you have a measurable $f>0$.

$\ln\frac{ f(2x)}{f(x)} = \ln \frac{2}{2} = \ln 1 $ if $x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{1,2\}$, $\ln\frac{ f(2(1))}{f(1)} = \ln \frac{1}{2} $ and $\ln  \frac{f(2(2))}{f(2)} = \ln\frac{2}{1} = \ln 2$. So the composition is not continuous at $1$ and $2$.

Comment: Can I use uniformity here?

Comment: Uniformity of what? What do you mean by uniform? 

Also, are you trying to add another property to $f$?

Comment: Oh sorry, i havent made myself clear, i mean if we are taking a uniform limit can i bring the limit inside the log?

Comment: Do you understand what uniform convergence is? You didn't give me a sequence of functions. What exactly is converging?

Comment: I know that $\frac{f(\lambda x)}{f(x)}\rightarrow1$ uniformly in $\lambda$, as $x\to\infty$ if this is any use.

Comment: I don't understand what a function converging uniformly in $\lambda$ means. Where is this question from? The statement makes no sense to me. I am going to sleep, maybe you'll have more luck if you post another question and context, like where you got it from, what your definitions of uniform convergence are (I only know how a sequence of functions uniformly converges, not how one function does so.)

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like a really pathological counterexample, consider $f(x)=\chi(x) + 1$ where $\chi$ is the characteristic function of the rationals. Then $f$ is positive, (Lebesgue) measurable, and nowhere continuous.

Your transformation will result in another everywhere discontinous function, so your limits won't exist.

Edit: Assuming $\lambda$ irrational.

Comment: I was trying this but then I saw that if $\lambda$ is rational, $\frac{f(\lambda x)}{f(x)} =1$ no matter whether $x$ was rational or irrational, because $\lambda x$ is rational if $x$ is irrational and irrational if $x$ is irrational so the numerators will always be equal to the denominators.

Comment: The only possible values of my proposd $f$ are 1 or 2, so the only possible ratios are 1/2, 1, or 2. I'm not sure how you find $\lambda x$ rational implies $x$ irrational.

Edit: I should also add that $\lambda$ was not given, so if we choose it irrational, we have a counterexample.

Comment: I don't follow. If $x$ is rational, $f(x) = 2$. Take $\lambda = 1$ for example. Then $f(\lambda x) = f(x) = 2$. So $\frac{f(\lambda x)}{f(x)} = \frac{2}{2} = 1$. If $x$ is irrational, $f(x) = 1$. Then $f(\lambda x) = f(x) = 1$ $\frac{f(\lambda x)}{f(x)} = \frac{1}{1} = 1$. Similarly the logarithms of the functions will be equal everywhere.

Edit: Saw your edit.